# TargetType for line in app.xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created a line to show the grid bottom line and it worked if I placed it on the `page.xaml`. I need to change the line during Orentiation, so I created a style on `app.xaml`. However it has `Application_UnhandledException` error. 
There is the code I used without sytle on the page and it work. Would someone show me how to make it work. Thanks in advance.

```
<Line   X1="0" X2="700" Y1="0" Y2="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5"/>
```

The following is the style for line on app.xaml

```
     <Style x:Key="queuePortraitLine" TargetType="Line">
        <Setter Property="X1" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="X2" Value="700"/>
        <Setter Property="Y1" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Y2" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>            
    </Style>
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the style on the item when the orientation changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code again and again. Finally I know why I got the error because I used the RelativeSource. It should be "StaticResource" for style in my page.